# how to download pdf file from public folder in symfony

Tags: php, html, symfony, download, dompdf

I'm using dompdf to generate invoices from html template, every work perfectly and the invoices are saved in the database with absolute filepath and filename, when I access to public/invoices I found all my pdf file there, I want to make a link button to download or open in the browser the file.

I create a link that take the absolute file like that :

```
{% for invoice in invoices %}
<tr>
  <td> {{ invoice.id }} </td>
  <td>{{ invoice.fileName }}</td>
  <td>{{ invoice.booking.user.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ invoice.booking.car.registrationNumber }}</td>
  <td>{{ invoice.booking.startDate | date('d-m-Y') }}</td>
  <td><a href="" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger">Archiver</a></td>
  <td><a href="{{ asset('invoices/' ~ invoice.filePath) }}) }}" style="color: #DDDDDD" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark"><i style="padding-right: 10px" class="fa fa-download"></i>Télecharger</a>
  </td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I got this error :

> No route found for "GET
> /home/sahnoun/Downloads/SousseCar/public/invoices/aKRyaziz.pdf)%20%7D%7D"
> (from "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/invoice/all")

Answer (score 0):

you are closing curly brackets two times when trying to use the asset() function, which generates the additional ")}}" in your output (url encoded: ")%20%7D%7D", which you can see in the error message). So naturally, this path does not exist.

```
...
// remove surplus '}})'
href="{{ asset('invoices/' ~ invoice.filePath) }}) }}"
...
```

Right:

```
href="{{ asset('invoices/' ~ invoice.filePath) }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

And really you should *not* expose invoice information to public Internet - that is basically huge security and user information leak - please move that logic inside your controller where you check if request user has proper rights to that information and then just return eg. `BinaryFileResponse` from that controller.